# How to create a bitmap adapter and display it in ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I'm a beginner in Kotlin and Android Studio and I would like to request for help to resolve this question:

1. Download an image from the URL;
2. Create Adapter module to receive bitmap;
3. Show image through `ImageView` object

---

1. I managed to resolve the first item with this simpler method. The next step is to improve with some library, but it's working.

```kotlin
private fun downloadImage(item: Item) = Thread {

        val imageConnection = URL(imageItem.url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

        try {
            if (photosConnection.responseCode == HTTP_OK) {
                runOnUiThread {
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(photosConnection.inputStream)
                    activityMainBinding.objImageView.apply {
                    // Implementar o novo Adapter                    
                    }
                }
            } else {
                runOnUiThread{
                    Toast.makeText(this, " Deu erro !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        } catch ( e: Exception)  {
                e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            imageConnection.disconnect()
        }
    }.start()
```

2. Create adapter module

I tried to make this adapter which is what I had as a reference. But inheriting from `ArrayAdapter` I understood that not compatible with Bitmap type. I was also unsure about the object (`android.R.layout`) normally I use (`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`)when they are String list applications. But in this case I didn't find similar, for example (`android.R.layout.image`).

```kotlin
class ImageAdapter (
    private val activityContext: Context,
    private val imageList: MutableList<Bitmap>
): ArrayAdapter<Bitmap>(activityContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, photosList) {


    private data class ImageHolder( val imageVw: ImageView )

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

        val imageView = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(activityContext)
                .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parent,false).apply {
                tag = ImageHolder(findViewById(android.R.id.text1))
                }

        (imageView.tag as ImageHolder)imageVw.setImageBitmap = imageList[position]

        return imageView
    }

}
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to keep it simple as possible

1. Use library to download image, e.g. [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), it's really simple and handling all the other things like url connection, thread and caching image.
2. For this you should use `RecyclerView` with creating your subclass of `RecyclerView.Adapter`.
3. Also done with the [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library.

Now for code, this is Activity layout, you have to put recyclerView somewhere to show the list with images, in my example `activity_image_adapter.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".simpleimageAdapter.ImageAdapterActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:itemCount="4"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_image"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And also create layout for image items, in my exampe `item_image.xml`

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:importantForAccessibility="no"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Next step you need to create custom adapter for the recyclerView:

```
class ImageAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder>() {

//Data list for the adapter, we will set data later
private var images: List<ImageItem> = emptyList()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ImageViewHolder {
    //Creates view holder which holds view. Recycler is reusing views because of performance
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    //Create view and attach it to the parent
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image, parent, false)
    return ImageViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //Called to show data with holder
    holder.onBind(item = images[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    //Returns items count this adapter shows
    return images.size
}


fun setData(list: List<ImageItem>) {
    this.images = list
    //Set new dataset for adapter and notify it about change
    //notifyDataSetChanged isn't the best option but for now let's keep it simple
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}


inner class ImageViewHolder(contentView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(contentView) {
    
    private val imageView: ImageView = contentView.findViewById(R.id.itemImageView)
    
    fun onBind(item: ImageItem) {
        //Load image with glide library and show it with imageView
        Glide.with(imageView.context)
            .load(item.url)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imageView)
    }
}
}
```

Now put it all together in activity code:

```
class ImageAdapterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_adapter)


    //Just simple data for the example
    val data = listOf(
        ImageItem(url = "https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/025/284/015/small_2x/close-up-growing-beautiful-forest-in-glass-ball-and-flying-butterflies-in-nature-outdoors-spring-season-concept-generative-ai-photo.jpg"),
        ImageItem(url = "https://i0.wp.com/picjumbo.com/wp-content/uploads/beautiful-nature-mountain-scenery-with-flowers-free-photo.jpg?w=600&quality=80"),
        ImageItem(url = "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/517188688/photo/mountain-landscape.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=A63koPKaCyIwQWOTFBRWXj_PwCrR4cEoOw2S9Q7yVl8=")
    )

    val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    val imageAdapter = ImageAdapter()
    //Set adapter to the recycler
    recyclerView.adapter = imageAdapter

    //Set data to adapter
    imageAdapter.setData(list = data)
}
}
```

After complete all part you will be able to show images, e.g like in the picture [image]

Comment: Hello @Miroslav, I really appreciate your help, thanks so much. For this demand I needed to use the volley library. But your explanation guided me to the solution.